# jqueryui: disable input width attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I'm importing **jquery-ui-form.css** to a page but I want to disable the `width` attribute of the `input` class (so it will revert to individual styles set on items).

I've tried:

```
$( "input" ).css( "width", "" );
```

to no avail.

I don't want to set it to 0 - just to get rid of that particular declaration.

Comment: If you have set a CSS style on the element, the `width` attribute will automatically be overridden. Can you post a fiddle which shows the problem.

Comment: @sphanley - I saw that posting. That's where I got the notion to try the `.css( "width", "" )`. Doesn't seem to work in this instance though.

Comment: But that's not what the accepted answer in that question suggests doing -- they suggest setting the attributes in question to their default value of 'auto', which is exactly what the answer you've accepted here does as well. The answers should confirm that this is a duplicate.

Comment: FWIW: this really isn't a duplicate. Setting the value to "" didn't work. The marked answer was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("input").width('auto')
```

http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 1):

If you use width as attribute instead of using in style 
You need to do this:

```
$("input").removeAttr("width");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `input`  is a class of an element. As you mentioned in question:

> **I want to disable the width attribute of the input class**

IF it's a class then, you should use [`class selector`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to selecting the element:

Try this:

```
$(".input").css("width", "auto");
```

OR

```
$(".input").width('auto');
```